# Регулярные выражения и (или) что-то еще

Tags: регулярные-выражения, искусственный-интеллект

Привет. Пользователь вводит свое имя в свободном формате:

```
Александр Сергеевич Зонов
Зонов Александр Сергеевич
А. С. Зонов
Зонов А. С.
Демидович Борис Павлович
Боря
Саша
Боря Демидович
Демидович Борис
```

Как c минимальной кровью и некоторой вероятностью ошибки или отказа (результат - пустая строка) из этого вытащить:

1. Имя и отчество, если они есть
2. Только имя, если нет ИО
3. Инициалы и фамилию, если это возможно и если не удались первые два пункта

?

Comment: Да, пятая строка хороша. Я вот сам не знаю фамилию Демидович он или Павлович ...

Comment: @Mike, вроде бы, по традиции или ФИО, или ИОФ. ОИФ это неформат и отказ - пустая строка. Ну, то есть так задумано, а на самом деле может быть и нет. Я понимаю, что задача достаточно сложная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала делай проверку на наличие пробелов, если нету, то это имя.

Далее если есть точка в строке, то через регулярки вытаскиваете:

```js
function getWithInitials(str) {
    var io = str.match(/([а-яё]\. ?){2}/gi)[0].trim();
    var fam = str.match(/([а-яё]{2,})/gi)[0].trim();
    return fam + ' ' + io;
}

console.log(getWithInitials('А. С. Зонов'));
console.log(getWithInitials('Зонов А. С.'));
```

Иначе вытаскиваете имя и отчество через [веб-сервис склонения по падежам «Морфер» 3.0](http://morpher.ru/ws3/#fio-split) для разделения строки на фамилию, имя и отчество. Код веб-сервиса открыт и находится на [GitHub](https://github.com/morpher-ru/Morpher.WebService.V3). Сервис выдает [ответ](https://ws3.morpher.ru/russian/declension?s=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%20%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) в формате:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Р>Александра Сергеевича Зонова</Р>
    <Д>Александру Сергеевичу Зонову</Д>
    <В>Александра Сергеевича Зонова</В>
    <Т>Александром Сергеевичем Зоновым</Т>
    <П>Александре Сергеевиче Зонове</П>
    <ФИО>
        <Ф>Зонов</Ф>
        <И>Александр</И>
        <О>Сергеевич</О>
    </ФИО>
</xml>
```